# Count keywords in each line of dataframe

Tags: python, regex, pandas, for-loop

I want to count the number sum of presence of each key word of my list in a given dataframe column for each line.

```py
d = {
    'Column_1': ['mango pret Orange No manner', ' préts No scan '], 
    'Column_2': ['read priority No', 'This is a priority noir '],
    'Column_3': ['No add', 'yep']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

list_1 = ['Apple', 'Mango' ,'Orange', 'pr[éeêè]t[s]?']
list_2 = ['weather', 'r[ea]d' ,'p[wr]iority', 'noir?']
list_3 = ['n[eéè]d','snow[s]?', 'blanc?']

dict = {
    "s1": ['Column_1', list_1],
    "s2": ['Column_1', list_3],
    "s3": ['Column_2', list_2],
    "s4": ['Column_3', list_3],
    "s5": ['Column_2','Column_3',list_1]
}

for elt in list(dict.keys()):
    #s1 s2 s3 print(elt)
    if len(dict[elt])<=2:
        d = Counter(re.findall(r'|'.join(dict[elt][1]).lower(), str(df[dict[elt][0]].str.lower())))
        print(d)
        #df[elt] = d 
        sum(d.values())
    elif len(dict[elt])>2:
        aa = Counter(re.findall(r'|'.join(dict[elt][2]).lower(), str(df[dict[elt][0]].str.lower())))
        bb = Counter(re.findall(r'|'.join(dict[elt][2]).lower(), str(df[dict[elt][1]].str.lower())))
        b = sum(bb.values()) 
        a = sum(aa.values()) 
        d = a +b 
        df[elt] = d
```

the result of my `print(d)` is below

```py
Counter({'mango': 1, 'pret': 1, 'orange': 1, 'préts': 1})
```

How can I do to change this code to give something like the dataframe df2 below

```py
d2 = {'s1': [3, 1], 's3':[2,1]}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=d2)
```

Comment: Suppose `list_1 = ['no']`. What should be the output for `dict['s5']` ? `d2['s5'] = [[1,1],[1,0]]` ?

Comment: it is [2, 0] . because it exists one time in first line of cloumn_2 and one time in column_3 (1+1 = 2)  . And don't exist in the second line of column_2 and column_3 so 0.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import re

d = {
  'Column_1': [u'mango pret Orange No manner', u' préts No scan '], 
  'Column_2': [u'read priority No', u'This is a priority noir '],
  'Column_3': [u'No add', u'yep']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

list_1 = [u'Apple', u'Mango' ,u'Orange', u'pr[éeêè]t[s]?' ]
list_2 = [u'weather', u'r[ea]d' ,u'p[wr]iority', u'noir?' ]
list_3 = [u'n[eéè]d',u'snow[s]?', u'blanc?' ]

my_dict = {
  "s1": ['Column_1', list_1],
  "s2": ['Column_1', list_3],
  "s3": ['Column_2', list_2],
  "s4": ['Column_3', list_3],
  "s5": ['Column_2','Column_3',list_1]
}

d2 = dict()
for key, lst in my_dict.items():
  # Distinguish between columns and regex (assuming regex are stored in lists)
  col_names = filter(lambda x: isinstance(x, str), lst)
  regex_lists = filter(lambda x: isinstance(x, list), lst)
  # Concatenate all regex
  regex_list = reduce(lambda x, y: x+y, regex_lists)
  # For the considered columns, apply regex search in each cell and count
  map_function = lambda cell: len(re.findall(r'|'.join(regex_list).lower(), str(cell).lower()))
  df_regex_count = df[col_names].applymap(map_function)
  # Convert to desired output with lists to make a new dataframe
  d2[key] = map(sum, df_regex_count.values.tolist())

df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=d2)
```

Output :

```
    s1  s2  s3  s4  s5
0   3   0   1   0   0
1   1   0   2   0   0
```

Note that s3 gives [1, 2] and not [2, 1] because `r[ea]d` doesn't catch `read` and `noir?` catches `noir`.

Comment: thank you .. Can you tell me do you add the 'u' before each word? Notes that my columns will be read from csv file

Comment: I was using python 2.7. It's the way to handle unicode strings. Otherwise `pr[éeêè]t[s]?` would not catch `préts`. If you're using python 2, take special care when reading utf-8 files.

Comment: Can you mark as solved or do you need more explanations ?

Comment: when i tried your code i had this error **TypeError: reduce() of empty sequence with no initial value** i was trying to solve it

Comment: If you copy paste this code, it works in python 2.7. It also works in python 3 if you do `from functools import reduce`. You must then adapt it to your use case. According to your error, you must have an empty `regex_lists`. Meaning, you must have a value in `my_dict` where you don't have a **list** of regex.

Comment: the error is that my regex is not a list it is of type **<class 'str'>
**

Comment: In your example, your regex are inside lists (`list_1`, ...). If it were not, you could not know the difference between a regex and a column name. Therefore, to comply with your syntax, you need to make a list with it (`['regex']`). Please mark as solved or be more specific in your post in the description of your problem.

Comment: now i succeded to convert class str to list.. got another error **AttributeError: ("'float' object has no attribute 'lower'", 'occurred at index COL Name')  **

Comment: Your dataframe contains more than strings. Quickfix : `map_function = lambda s: len(re.findall(r'|'.join(regex_list).lower(), str(s).lower()))`.

Comment: @This is your problem solved ? If you have some other issue not stated in your problem description please open another ticket and marked this one as solved. I added comments for you to better understand the solution.

Comment: Hello @Arius thank you for your solution. i tried it but there a prob . When i have for example `mangodb` and in my list of words i have `mango` it detects it and return 1. So k must detect just the whole word.